# Explanation for error handling in nextJS getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is an example how I'm using `getServerSideProps` to stream some video data.
Now I want to implement some error handling and I think I'm messing up a few things.

So there are a few possible errors I want to catch (and handle correctly):

1. Wrong request method
2. Missing parameter (hash)
3. DB connection failed
4. openDownloadStream error

For my understanding the `try/catch` should collect all errors which are occuring in the `try` part.
But how do I handle those errors? Should I...

- throw the error
- call console.error()
- use `res()`

to get the best display of the error message. Mongodb will give me some other error structure then any other function which is failing.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  res,
  req: { method },
  query: { hash }
}) => {
  if (method !== 'GET') {
    res.statusCode = 405
    res.end() // Is this correct?
    return
  }
  if (!hash) return { notFound: true }

  try {
    const database = await mongodb() // catch connection error
    const bucket = new GridFSBucket(database)

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' })
    bucket
      .openDownloadStream(hash)
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        res.write(chunk)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        res.end()
      }) 
      .on('error', (err) => {
        // catch this error
      })     
  } catch (error) {
    // how to handle `error` correctly?
    res.statusCode = 500
    res.json({ error });
    if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    throw error
  }
}
```